# What is the difference between using @XmlElement before field and before getter declaration?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I can declare JAXB element in two ways:

```
@XmlElement
public int x;
```

or

```
private int x;

@XmlElement
public int getX(){...}
```

The first variant, AFAIK, creates getter, mapped to XML, anyway. What is the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It relates to the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation.

- `XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` : Fields are bound to XML only when they are explicitly annotated by some of the JAXB annotations.
- `XmlAccessType.FIELD`:  Getter/setter pairs are bound to XML only when they are explicitly annotated by some of the JAXB annotations

Update to explain based on comment:

Let's consider a simple xml that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <value>someValue</value>
</root>
```

And we have a class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
//@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DemoRoot {

    @XmlElement
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If you try to unmarshal using `XmlAccessType.FIELD` and the `@XmlElement` annotation above the field, then you will unmarshal fine.

If you use `XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` you will receive the following error:

IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Class has two properties of the same name "value"

This is because it takes into consideration both the explicitly annotated with `@XmlElement` field 'value' and the getters/setters.

And vice versa if you move the `@XmlElement` annotation on the getter/setter.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my illiteracy, but could you elaborate your answer somewhat? An example, please, please?

Comment: my apologies, I will make an example now

Answer (score 2):

The use of @XMLElement (and similar annotations) before fields or before getters is well explained in this post: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html.

The following annotation before a class determines the XML bindings of fields/getters:

- @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER): public fields, annotated fields and properties
- @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY): annotated fields and properties
- @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD): fields and annotated properties
- @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE): annotated fields and annotated properties